# Node.JS - Handling Certain Types of Promise Rejections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, unhandled-exception

In Node.JS, I know that you can use the `unhandledRejection` event to catch unhandled errors. However, I only want to catch a certain type of error. How can I do this?

Comment: which type? ...

Comment: @JonasW. well Im not sure how to find out what type it is... how do I get like its error code or something?

Comment: What do you expect to happen with other types of errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `unhandledRejection` [node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection):

The listener function is called with the following arguments:

`reason`  |  The object with which the promise was rejected (typically an Error object).

`p` the `Promise` that was rejected.

So, you can check the event `reason`... ex.:

```
 if (evt.reason === 'Some specific Error') {
 // do something
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this out by adding this: `process.on("unhandledRejection", (reason, p) => {
  if (reason !== "DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions") {
    console.log(reason)
  }
})` but it still got logged